# Jquery attribute rel is screwing everything up

Tags: jquery

This is hopefully my last question, for today :P.

I have **10** .photo divs with different image each one. html code bellow:

```
<div class="photo"><!-- Start Photo -->
<div class="transparency"></div>
    <div class="performer"><p><? echo $perf; ?></p></div>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="jquery" rel="<? echo ''.$perf.''; ?>"><img src="<? echo ''.$pic.''; ?>" width="180" height="135" alt="<? echo ''.get_the_title().''; ?>" style="display:block"/></a>
</div><!-- End Photo -->
```

This is what my jquery code does: when i hover a photo div, it loads a flash movie. When I hover out of that div, i want the initial photo to be displayed.

Here is my jquery code:

```
    $(".photo").hoverIntent(function() {
    $(this).html('<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,24,0" width="100" height="100"><param name="movie" value="http://static.awempire.com/flash/live_feeds/live_feed.swf" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="wmode" value="transparent" /><param name="flashvars" value="appletroot=http://static.awempire.com/flash/live_feeds/&appletskin=template8/template01.swf&appletcol=900000&psid=ddany23&campaign_id=20520&pstour=t1&psprogram=REVS&site=jsm&flags=137438953473,137438953504,1,32&lp_lang=auto" /><embed src="http://static.awempire.com/flash/live_feeds/live_feed.swf" width="100" height="100" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" flashvars="appletroot=http://static.awempire.com/flash/live_feeds/&appletskin=template8/template01.swf&appletcol=900000&psid=ddany23&campaign_id=20520&pstour=t1&psprogram=REVS&site=jsm&flags=137438953473,137438953504,1,32&lp_lang=auto"></embed></object>');
}, function() {
    $(this).html('' + $(".jquery").attr("rel") + '');
});
```

**The problem is, the rel does not corespond with each image. I mean, it gets the rel to the immediate .photo div, mixes them, etc... pretty strange**

It should work, i should have the rel coresponding to it's own .photodiv. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made id work like this:

```
    $(".photo").hoverIntent(function() {
    $(this).html('<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,24,0" width="100" height="100"><param name="movie" value="http://static.awempire.com/flash/live_feeds/live_feed.swf" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="wmode" value="transparent" /><param name="flashvars" value="appletroot=http://static.awempire.com/flash/live_feeds/&appletskin=template8/template01.swf&appletcol=900000&psid=ddany23&campaign_id=20520&pstour=t1&psprogram=REVS&site=jsm&flags=137438953473,137438953504,1,32&lp_lang=auto" /><embed src="http://static.awempire.com/flash/live_feeds/live_feed.swf" width="100" height="100" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" flashvars="appletroot=http://static.awempire.com/flash/live_feeds/&appletskin=template8/template01.swf&appletcol=900000&psid=ddany23&campaign_id=20520&pstour=t1&psprogram=REVS&site=jsm&flags=137438953473,137438953504,1,32&lp_lang=auto"></embed></object>');
}, function() {
    $(this).html('' + $(this).attr("title") + '');

});
```

Gave the photo div a title instead.

Answer (score 1):

`$(".jquery").attr("rel")` will get the `rel` attribute from the *first* element with class "jquery" (out of the entire document).  You want to get the rel from the .jquery element in the current block, which would be

```
$(".jquery", $(this)).attr("rel")
```

or fully:

```
$(this).html('' + $(".jquery", $(this)).attr("rel") + '');
```

Comment: Thank you man, sounds like it should work, but now I get undefined, instead of the rel value

Answer (score 0):

`$(".jquery").attr("rel")` translates to give me the elements with class `jquery` and get the `rel` attribute. But you haven't assigned any class to your images. I would say check the generated HTML content and see if it is right.